# How to display all images of a directory using javascript in Grails

Tags: javascript, grails

I have my images under image folder

```
 '../images/'
```

I need to display them one after the other in series using grails.

need some idea.

Thankyou

Bhanu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to collect all your image names within your controller, pass them to the view and show them using the [grails image tag](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Tags/img.html).

To collect all your image names you need the path to your grails app:

```
def imageDir = grailsAttributes.getApplicationContext().getResource("/images/").getFile().toString()
```

Collect image names:

```
def images = []
new File(imageDir).eachFileMatch (~/.*.png/) { file ->
    images << file.getName()
}
```

Pass them to the view and show them:

```
<g:each in="${images}" var="image">
    <g:img dir="images" file="$image" />
</g:each>
```

The code is not tested but should work respectively show you the direction.

Comment: All the images are displaying at a time,but i need them like one after other(slide show) any guidance.

Comment: Thats a HTML / JS topic. I would suggest to read some docs / tutorials to find out how to manage that. The easiest way is using jquery with an slideshow plugin.